# Password resets on shutdown

Tags: noobs, password, reset

First point I am completely new to the Raspberry Pi.

Having purchased a Raspberry Pi with the NOOBS SD card, I completed the basic install and have access to the Pi.

I wanted to have this accessible "Headless," so I went about switching on SSH. With this done, I found that I couldn't access it via SSH using the default name and password. After a lot of faffing around, I decided to try changing the password. In doing so I was able to get onto the Pi (I assume for some reason the default password was wrong).

The issue I now have is that when I reboot the Pi, the password is lost. I can reset it ok but it just defaults again at reboot.

I have been using the sudo raspi-config command and making the change via the LXTerminal

Any help welcome

Comment: Hammer to crack a walnut. Reinstalled Raspian, issue resolved, case closed

Comment: I'm curious... did you install the official `Raspbian` image or reinstall the `Noobs` image?

Comment: So thats an intreresting question. I reinstalled the Raspian Noobs image. There are tow points of note - 1. the fact that the password kept restiing and 2. that the default password at the time was not accepted (hence the reason for resetting the Pwd in the first place.

Both of these issues were resolved in re-installing from the same issue. I can only surmise that there was some kind of corruption on the original install.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few possibilities here:

1. Is your SD card write protected? This would prevent your changes from taking effect, and the `passwd` command would not necessarily give you an error message.
2. Are you actually changing the password for the correct user? It may sound silly, but double-check which user you are changing the password as, and make sure you haven't switched to root just before hand (for example, by running `su -`)
3. Does your user have SSH privileges? Try the command `groups`
4. Is SSH really turned on? The SSH deamon is what you turned on, correct?